# RedirectMatch 301 how to exclude URL(s)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a RedirectMatch rule in place which looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1/$2/$3
```

It is intended to match any existing WordPress posts formatted /year/month/postname and redirect to /blog/year/month/postname. It works fine, but I have recently been asked to add an exception to the RedirectMatch. Previously, I have simply added an exclusion rule directly above but it does not have any affect in this case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2014/07/example-blog-post/$
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1/$2/$3
```

I have also tried setting the exclusion within the RedirectMatch rule itself, but either I am doing it incorrectly or it just does not work. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (^!/2014/07/example-blog-post/$|^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$) http://www.example.com/blog/$1/$2/$3
```

And:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (^!/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/example-blog-post/$|^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$) http://www.example.com/blog/$1/$2/$3
```

My question is how do I go about adding one (or more) exclusions to such a RedirectMatch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is part of `mod_rewrite` that only works with `RewriteRule`

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2014/07/example-blog-post/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava, you've helped clear up my confusion. I am unfortuantely getting a 500 error, Apache log is suggesting bad flag delimiters `[Mon Jul 21 15:54:34 2014] [alert] [client ::1] /Users/.../.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: Many thanks anubhava, works great. Only issue I had was I had to ensure this was placed before any other RedirectRule, otherwise it never got parsed. Thanks.